# Multi-Date queries in JPA repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm having an issue with creating a Query in Spring Data JPA.
I want to return a List that consists of objects that are AFTER Date1 and BEFORE Date2.

Additional Question: How do I get JPA to return a single column. For instance, if I wanted to return one column of the Reservation table instead of a list of Reservation objects.

I want my query to be the equivalent of:

```
SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE check_in_date >= '2022-12-18' AND check_out_date <= '2022-12-30';
```

I thought that the correct method name would be:

```
public List<Reservation> findByCheckInDateAfterAndCheckOutDateBefore(Date checkIn, Date checkOut);
```

checkInDate/checkOutDate are the names of the fields in the Reservation object.
However, it is not returning the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

You want `>=` but method has only `After` it is missing `or equal`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject
does not have `AfterThanEqual` maybe `GreaterThanEqual` works with dates

or You can try using negation
`public List<Reservation> findByCheckInDateNotBeforeAndCheckOutDateNotAfter(Date checkIn, Date checkOut);`

also you could enable sql logging as shown here https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot and verify executed sql

Comment: GreaterThanEqual and LessThanEqual are both valid for Date queries. Thanks a ton!